# IdentifyTask for "hollow" polygon (using ArcGIS API for JavaScript)

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, polygon, web-mapping, identify

I have a web map application set up that's currently testing on a variety of Dynamic Map Service layer types, including points, lines, and polygons. This application includes a tool that makes use of ItentifyTask to allow a user to click on the map and get a popup with attribute information for any visible layers at that point. This tool works perfectly for points, lines, and SOLID polygons, but it does NOT work for polygons that are displayed with a hollow symbology (ex: county polygons displayed to only show the outline of the county). In this case, the execution of the IdentifyTask returns NO results. If I click on the outline of the feature it works fine, but not if I click on the hollow interior.

Is there a good workaround for this? For our needs, we really do need the ability to identify such layers, and the hollow symbology is our standard for such layers.

Answer (score 1):

instead of null fill, use a completely transparent fill, like [this](http://jsbin.com/woqijumi/3/edit?html,js,output)

reference: https://twitter.com/derekswingley/status/487335272825094144

Comment: Is there a way to to this in ArcMap, when the GIS analyst is setting up ther service? Because I'd like for the application coding to be generalized for use with any input map service layer, and not have to change the rendering of the layer through the application coding itself.

Comment: AFAIK, you can't modify the transparency of fill and outline independently in ArcMap.